# Stop flexslider when video is playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, flexslider

I am using `flexslider` plugin in order to show a picture and video. The slides are changed automatically and it's fine with me. The problem is, that when user plays the video (iframe from youtube), `flexslider` continues to change slides.

I've checked the documentation and found `pauseOnHover`, which kinda does the trick, but i'd much rather prefer it to pause when video is started and continue when video is paused/has ended. Any suggestions on how to handle this?

**EDIT**

Here's the div where iframe is opened:

```
<div class="span6 animated fadeInLeftBig" id="main-media">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/someID?version=3&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="iframe-id"></iframe>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to solve this, is to use YouTube API, somethnig like this:

```
//Implement Youtube API
(function(){ 
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api"; /* Load Player API*/
  var before = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  before.parentNode.insertBefore(s, before);
})();

var YT_ready=(function(){var b=[],c=false;return function(a,d){if(a===true){c=true;while(b.length){b.shift()()}}else if(typeof a=="function"){if(c)a();else b[d?"unshift":"push"](a)}}})();
YT_ready(function() {
    (function($) {
            var frameID = "yourIframeID"
            var player = new YT.Player(frameID, {
                    events: {
                        "onStateChange": function(event) {
                            if (event.data == 1 || event.data == 3) {
                                $('.flexslider').flexslider("pause");
                            }
                            else if (event.data == 0 || event.data == 2 || event.data == 5) {
                                $('.flexslider').flexslider("play");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        });



    })(jQuery);
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    YT_ready(true)
}
```

Comment: Hmm, something doesn't seem right. I've entered iframe id into "frameID", but it doesn't react at all. Console doesn't show any errors related to this either though...

Comment: your html markup would be nice... the iframe src should have "?enablejsapi=1" at the end..

Comment: I've added part with iframe in question.

Comment: Actually no, there is an error. Console points at line with (jQuery). And the error is: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Removing part (function($) { }) lines fixed the issue, i'm now able to stop/start slide show depending on state of player. Thank you!